# React: faster way to handle state change between OnMouseDown and OnMouseUp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a window I want only to be draggable from the top bar, similar to... a GUI window.

I have a state update based off OnMouseDown and OnMouseUp events on the top bar. However, the updates seem to be slow. It only works every other time I try and drag and drop it. It appears that on odd attempts OnMouseUp doesn't update properly, or is slow to update (the print statements are different from the actual value). Is there a better way to be updating the state here when the user is clicking the `contentTopBar`?

```
class GenericWindow extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {draggable:true}
  }

  render(){    
    return( <motion.div 
                    drag={this.state.draggable}
                    dragMomentum={false}
                    >
                    <div 
            className="contentTopBar homeBar"
            onMouseDown={()=>{this.setState({draggable:true});console.log(`should be TRUE, is: ${this.state.draggable}`)}} // ** mouse down
            onMouseUp={()=>{this.setState({draggable:false});console.log(`should be FALSE, is: ${this.state.draggable}`)}}  // ** mouse up
            > 
            {this.props.title} 
            </div>
                    <div className="ContentWindowContent">
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
            </motion.div>
        )
  }
}
```

edit: note I am using the framer motion module for dragging, hence the motion.div.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making this work in a roundabout way, I am interested if anyone can suggest something better. I added an extra state `{mouseUp:false}`, and changed the two onMouseUp / onMouseDown lines to the following:

```
              onMouseEnter={ e=>this.setState({draggable:true, mouseUp:false}) }  
              onMouseLeave={ e=>this.state.mouseUp && this.setState({draggable:false, mouseUp:false}) }

              onMouseDown={e=>this.setState({draggable:true,mouseUp:false})}
              onMouseUp={ e=>{this.setState({mouseUp:true})} }
```

I am saving a mouseUp state because sometimes my cursor drags faster than the topbar area and it cancels the drag event, but I found this to be the most robust